# Variable string con el valor System.IO.FileStream

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

estoy desarrollando un proyecto, en el que agrego imágenes a un formulario, al hacer el envío al servidor hay una función que almacena la ruta en una tabla (o esa es la intención), pero cuando escribo en la tabla, validando el valor que esta escrito es `System.IO.FileStream` en lugar de la ruta donde se guardo el archivo, a continuación muestro parte del proceso de recepción del formulario en el servidor:

```
var size = inputevidence.Sum(f => f.Length);
            var filePaths = new List<string>();
            string listadeevidencias= "";
            foreach (var formFile  in inputevidence) 
            {
                x++;
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var filePath = "/Evidence";
                    var filename = elementovaribale+x.ToString()+formFile.FileName.ToString();
                    filePaths.Add(filePath);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath, filename), FileMode.Create)) 
                    {
                         formFile.CopyTo(stream);
                         listadeevidencias = listadeevidencias.ToString() + stream.ToString() + "#";
                    }
                }
            }
```

En el formulario, se pueden agregar mas de una imagen, mi lógica (no tan buena) fue crear una cadena donde el nombre del archivo es compuesto de algunos valores del formulario, que a su vez es agregada a la cadena `listadeevidencias` que va a almacenar la ruta completa de cada fotografía separada por el carácter `#` que envío al servidor, en el servidor tengo una función dentro de SP para leer esa cadena e ir insertando las rutas que estan entre `#` de momento, funciona parcialmente, porque si envío n imagenes hace los `insert` pero en la tabla escribe `System.IO.FileStream`, muestro parte de mi SP:

```
WHILE(@contador<LEN(@listadeevidencias))
BEGIN
SELECT @Rutevidencia = SUBSTRING(@listadeevidencias,1,CHARINDEX('#',@listadeevidencias)-1)
INSERT INTO Evidencia(IDScrap,rutevidencia) VALUES(@ID_UltimoInsert,@Rutevidencia)
SET @listadeevidencias = SUBSTRING(@listadeevidencias,(CHARINDEX('#',@listadeevidencias)+1),LEN(@listadeevidencias))
SET @contador = @contador + 1
END
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la cadena que envío al SP sea legible como la ruta que arme antes de enviar la cadena? Adjunto una imagen de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: `stream.ToString()` devuelve **System.IO.Stream** porque no tiene una sobrecarga propia. Esta usando la que hereda de `object`, que devuelve un string con el tipo del objeto.

Comment: Me encerré en mi propio mundo y no me percate, que si ya tenia todos los elementos donde sabia la ruta completa, porque no armarla de nuevo y eso mismo insertar en DB, muy tonto de mi parte

Answer (score 0):

Resolví mi problema armando la cadena `listadeevidencias` elemento por elemento así me entregaba la cadena tal cual la necesitaba, lo arme de la siguiente manera:

```
listadeevidencias = listadeevidencias+"D:"+"\\"+"Evidence"+"\\"+filename.ToString()+"#";
```

La diagonales dobles para escapar de la misma secuencia de escape y poder insertar como una ruta valida, quedando así en la DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor aún `listadeevidencias += @"D:\Evidence\" + ...`